# Create a patch from stash

Tags: git

Need to create a patch from stash and apply the patch on another branch.

Tried `git format-patch -1 stash@{0} > P1.patch`  and also `git stash show -p > P1.patch`

Unable to apply either of the patches created. `git am <` or `git apply`

Comment: Why not change to the branch and do `git stash apply stash@{0}`?

Comment: I need to save the patch file in artifacts and apply the patch on various machines.

Comment: Try: patch -p1 < P1.patch